# How to fix binding on image element

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am sending an object to component. This component looping with v-for. But component can not list images

I tried to send property and i get property from parent component.

```
<div class="container">
      <Card v-for="card in cards" :card="card"/>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  import Card from "./Card";

  export default {
    name: "GameCards",
    components: {Card},
    data() {
      return {
        cards: [
          {id: 1, comp: 'Card', img: '/src/assets/1.jpg'},
          {id: 2, comp: 'Card', img: '/src/assets/2.jpg'},
          {id: 3, comp: 'Card', img: '/src/assets/3.jpg'},
          {id: 4, comp: 'Card', img: '/src/assets/4.jpg'},
          {id: 5, comp: 'Card', img: '/src/assets/5.jpg'}
        ]
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

And this is Card.vue

```
<template>
  <div class="card">
    <img :src="card.img" alt="Test img">
    {{card.img}}
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    name: "Card",
    props: ['card']
  }
</script>
```

Pictures can not visible. Just blank cards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
<template>
  <div class="card">
    <img :src="getImgUrl(card.img)" alt="Test img">
    {{card.img}}
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "Card",
  props: ["card"],
  methods: {
    getImgUrl(pic) {
      return require("../assets/" + pic);
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

With relativ paths.

```
<template>
  <div class="container">
    <Card v-for="card in cards" :card="card" :key="card.img"/>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import Card from "./Card";

export default {
  name: "GameCards",
  components: { Card },
  data() {
    return {
      cards: [
        { id: 1, comp: "Card", img: "/logo.png" },
        { id: 2, comp: "Card", img: "/logo.png" },
        { id: 3, comp: "Card", img: "/logo.png" },
        { id: 4, comp: "Card", img: "/logo.png" },
        { id: 5, comp: "Card", img: "/logo.png" }
      ]
    };
  }
};
</script>
```

Codesandbox example: https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-template-e1jsh

Comment: I did not know the require() using, thanks it works.

Answer (score 0):

Your URLs are absolute (because they begin with `/`) - so they are used intact and thus refer to your public folder. You should ensure that these files do exist inside `/public` folder in your project. Otherwise, if they reside in the `/src` folder - you should instead refer to them as `@/assets/1.jpg` or even `~@/assets/1.jpg` (you should test which one works for you)

Carefully read the documentation - https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/html-and-static-assets.html#static-assets-handling